# Why does a flex-item with a display: flex collapses unless you give it an explicit width of 100%?

Tags: html, css

```css
    .container { 
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .component {
      display: flex;
      //width: 100%;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="component"></div>
    </div>
```

without the `width: 100%`, the `.component` collapses, and is not shown. With `width: 100%`, it is shown.

My question is why?
`display: flex` has a `width` of `100%` by default, so why do I need to explicitly set `width` to `100%` again?

I know that the `.component` is turned into a `flex-item` which has a default `width` of `auto`, which means the `width` collapses to its content, and since the `.component` has no content, it collapses to 0, but it has a `display` of `flex`, which has a default `width` of `100%`, so I should not have to set the `width` to `100%` explicitly.

Comment: A flex item shrinks by default, but doesn't grow by default. If there's no content, it obviously shrinks to 0 width.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct, but flawed on some aspects. The reason a flex element has width 100% "by default" isn't because that's `flex`'s doing, but rather because it is treated as a block element (where `inline-flex` are treated as inline elements).

The reason a flex within a flex doesn't magically grow "by default" is because a flex's child element essentially has its `flex` property set to `0 auto` unless specified (which is short for don't grow, don't shrink, basis is auto). Which sorts of acts as if you manually set `width` to `auto`.

Comment: The outerHTML of a flex element is treated as a block element which has a default width of 100%, but if the flex element is inside a flex container, then the flex container will turn its flex element children into flex-items with an explicit width of 0, which overwrites their default outerHTML width, so that's why you have to explicitly set the width to 100% again. Is that correct?

Comment: So if that's correct, then I have one more additional question. Are you familiar with shadow DOM and Light (regular) DOM?

Comment: The width is "set to" auto, not 0. Alongside flex-grow to 0, and flex-shrink to 0

Comment: I assume it should work the same with shadow DOM

Comment: So, it's set to 'auto', but because of the flex-shrink, it collapses to 0?

Comment: Also, no, it doesn't work the same way in shadow DOM, which is what led me to ask this question in the first place. I have a web component made with Stencil.js, and it uses shadow DOM. The component itself is like a wrapper which contains the elements inside. The wrapper can be styled with the `:host { .. }` selector. The element inside is flex, and when you nest the component inside another flex container, it collapses even with width: 100%. It only works if you set the width of the :host i.e. wrapper itself to 100%. Do you think you know what I mean?

Comment: I think that's a bit outside the scope of the question, but I assume that's a property specific to `:host` then. I haven't found anything about "default styles", but I'd assume based on your example that `:host` is treated as `inline-block` unless display is specified otherwise.